# Switching between virtual terminals

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use the `chvt` command to switch to another virtual terminal. Now I issue the `exit` command to logout from it.

My question is: how can I now return (not using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*x*</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*x*</kbd>) to the previous terminal where I issued `chvt` command?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear. 
If you want a way to switch back to the previous VT you were on,
*whatever it is*, without having to remember its number,
I don’t know of any super-easy way. 
(There is a somewhat straightforward way:
write a shell script that calls `chvt`,
and have it “remember” (in a file) what VT you were on
the last time you ran that script. 
Then you will be able to use that file to remember where to go “back” to.)

But, if you’re willing to remember (in your head)
and type the number of the previous VT, it’s easy:

```
chvt {previous_VT_number}; exit
```

For example, if you’re logged in to VTs 1 and 2, and VT 1 is active, type

```
chvt 2; exit
```

The shell will execute the two commands in succession
(as it always does when you say something like
`command1; command2`). 
The `chvt 2` command, as you know, will switch you to VT 2. 
And then the `exit` command will be processed *by the shell on VT 1*,
without switching the display back there.

---

Apparently I have, as I feared, misunderstood the question.

Suppose (as in your comment) that you’re logged in to VTs 1 and 2,
and VT 2 is active (e.g., because you issued `chvt 2` from VT 1),
and then you type `exit` on VT 2,
so now you’re logged out and you’re looking at the VT 2 login screen,
and now you want to switch back to VT 1
without typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. 
You can do this:

1. Login again (to VT 2), and
2. type `chvt 1; exit`

Comment: Ok but i've asked is there a way to return back to the previous VT after exited from the one i just switched used `chvt`? That is I issued chvt 2 from VT1,  then on VT2 exit, and now how to swich back to VT1 couse now left out with VT2 login screen.

Comment: Please don’t whine at me for misunderstanding your question when you’ve written an unclear question and I’ve *said* that I’m not sure I understand it.  Instead, edit your question to make it clear and complete. It just might help if you would explain your rationale.  Why do you want a solution other than Ctrl+Alt+F1?